# Property 'password' does not exist on type 'Document'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose, nestjs

I have an PartnerSchema

```
export const PartnerSchema: Schema = new Schema({
  id: {
        type: Number,
        require: [true, "EL id es necesario"],
        default: 0
  },
  password :{type:String},

});
```

and Im trying to hash the password of the schema before save the document in database with this function in the same file

```
PartnerSchema.pre('save', function(next){

  let user = this;

  // Make sure not to rehash the password if it is already hashed
  if(!user.isModified('password')) return next();

  // Generate a salt and use it to hash the user's password
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {

      if(err) return next(err);

      bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, (err, hash) => {

          if(err) return next(err);
          user.password = hash;
          next();

      });

  });
```

But in the `bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, (err, hash) => {` im getting this error

```
Property 'password' does not exist on type 'Document'
```

Why im getting this error id user = this  with all the properties ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define interface for your pre hook

```
export interface IUser extends mongoose.Document {
  password: string
}

PartnerSchema.pre<IUser>('save', function(next){...}
```

Comment: GitHub issue on mongoose: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5046#issuecomment-412114160

Answer (score 1):

**You can follow this code**

> You can define model file this code and require bcryptjs

```
PartnerSchema.pre('save',function(next){

   this.password= bcrypt.hashsync(this.password,10)

   next()

})
```

Comment: Still getting the error ```Property 'password' does not exist on type 'Document'```

Answer (score 1):

You can also cast the `user` type to a `PartnerDocument` type:

```
PartnerSchema.pre('save', function(next){

  let user = <PartnerDocument>this;
  ...

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the type can be solved in a cleaner way

Define the interface:

```
interface UserSchema extends mongoose.Document {
    password: string;
}
```

and then use as a first parameter of your pre hook like this:

```
userSchema.pre("save", async function (this: UserSchema, next: NextFunction) {...
```